# How to make fields in a class transient(contextually speaking not the java keyword)?

Tags: java, caching

I have a background thread that reads data from a data source on a specific time interval. The thread stores the data into a class(lets call it `DataStore`). The objects created from the class are stored in a `List`.

Now the problem is some of the fields in the class get updated on every read from the database, while other fields will remain unchanged after the first read and that means the objects in the `List` will contain some data that will be replaced on the next run of the thread. What I want to do is make the fields that will be updated somehow transient after I process the data. I don't want to keep them in memory while the thread is sleeping. The fields that remain unchanged and those get updated are known ahead of time.

One approach I can think of is create another class which is immutable containing the fields that get updated and add it as a field of the main class `DataStore`. This will force me to create a new instance of the immutable class every time the thread runs which will free the old object created on the previous run. The problem with this approach is it will still keep the data in memory while the thread is sleeping. To avoid this I can go through the objects in the list and set the references to `null` after processing the data. But I am not sure if that is a good programming practice.

So my question is, are there better ways to address this scenario? Is the approach I mentioned acceptable?

Appreciate your help!!

Comment: I think you're on the right track with having an immutable class that holds the transient fields.  However, you haven't mentioned how long the transient fields actually need to remain available.  Can you not null the internal reference to that immutable object as soon as it is accessed?

Comment: Thanks for reply @VGR. Here is what the thread is doing, read data and put them in the list(transient and non-transient), process data,save processed data, go to sleep. This cycle repeats every time the thread wakes up. The transient fields are needed while the data is being processed. Once the results are calculated and saved, there is no need to keep the transient fields. As you have mentioned I can set the reference to null once the data is processed but I am also asking this question to see if there a better way to do it and see if others have better way of solving the problem.

Comment: @VGR What kind of approach would you use?

Comment: I think I would null out the data as soon as it is accessed, though I'm not certain I fully understand your needs.

Comment: I may have made it look complicated than it is. I think I will go with setting the reference to null.